# install g++-7: unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to install gcc-7 together with g++-7. First I have installed gcc7 successfully. Of course I've done

```
sudo apt update
```

Then I'm unable to install g++7:

```
anton@AntonLinux:/$ sudo apt install g++-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-7-dev (< 7.5.0-6~) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried removing libgcc-7-dev but it didn't help. Currently the following related packages are installed:

```
anton@AntonLinux:/$ apt list --installed | grep libgcc

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libgcc-10-dev/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-4.8-dev/bionic,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-6-dev/bionic-updates,now 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-s1/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-s1/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 i386 [installed,automatic]
libgcc1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:10.1.0-1]
libgcc1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 i386 [installed,upgradable to: 1:10.1.0-1]


anton@AntonLinux:/$ apt list --installed | grep libc6

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libc6-dbg/unstable,now 2.31-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6/unstable,now 2.31-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6/unstable,now 2.31-4 i386 [installed,automatic]


anton@AntonLinux:/$ apt list --installed | grep gcc

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gcc-10-base/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-10-base/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 i386 [installed,automatic]
gcc-10/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-4.8-base/bionic,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-4.8/bionic,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
gcc-6-base/bionic-updates,now 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6/bionic-updates,now 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-7-base/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-8-base/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.4.0-4]
gcc-8-base/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 i386 [installed,upgradable to: 8.4.0-4]
gcc/unstable,now 4:10.2.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-10-dev/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-4.8-dev/bionic,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-6-dev/bionic-updates,now 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-s1/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-s1/unstable,now 10.2.0-13 i386 [installed,automatic]
libgcc1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:10.1.0-1]
libgcc1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 i386 [installed,upgradable to: 1:10.1.0-1]
```

Comment: Did you run `apt update` ? Can't you use a more recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)? The current one is [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/). Consider [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64306555/edit)ing your questionn to improve it. Consider repeating your commands tomorrow

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch of course I've done ```apt update```. I can't use GCC10, I need GCC7.

Comment: You could compile [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) from its source code